# How to use GCP vision trained model in Object Detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, object-detection-api

I trained a object detection model through vision in GCP, How can i use that model in normal tensorflow object detection api provided by google in GitHub?
It gives 3 options for exporting the model which one to use & how?

Comment: what would be the exact use you would make of the exported model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the model in the local drive from the cloud and load this model into the object detection api, the function load_model usually downloads pre-trained model from URL, you need to give the path of the local saved model here. The API that you are looking for is tf.saved_model.load, also update the path for labels correctly in PATH_TO_LABELS.